# PPTX Passes Validation, but PowerPoint Still Repairs

Tags: xml, ms-office, powerpoint, openxml

I am building out a PowerPoint presentation by using some XML templates from an example presentation. So far it has gone pretty smoothly, but in my last iteration I ran into the following problem:

1) PPTX file opens up fine in both LibreOffice and Google Slides.

2) Passing it through the Open XML Productivity Tool validator shows no errors.

3) Opening file in PowerPoint results in the file being "repaired". When I compare the repaired file to the original in the productivity tool, the repaired file just stripped all the content out of 3 of the slides.

How can I go about figuring out what the actual PowerPoint program does not like about my PPTX file? How can the program have problems with the file when the validator gives no errors?

Any advice or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Anyway you can share the troublesome pptx file?

Comment: @PatricK No, because the point is not to help with this one file, its to help me solve a problem with any subsequent files I generate.

Comment: No sample file means we can't **test** other than suggestions. Have you tried "Open Read Only" or "Open and Repair" in PowerPoint and see if it remove slides?

Comment: @PatricK As I stated, when I open the presentation, PowerPoint does the repair operation. It does in fact remove slides. That's the problem. It is apparently finding something wrong with my XML for the slides, and just removing it entirely.

Comment: What happens if you open the pptx file via macro with [Presentations.Open2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744741(v=office.14).aspx) method, setting **ReadOnly:=msoTrue** and **OpenAndRepair:=msoFalse**? My last resort is to extract contents in the "repaired" pptx and compare xmls manually, observe what MS removed/injected and then more research on root cause... [This msdn may help.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd926741(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: @PatricK Thank you for your suggestion, but I have already tried opening the file as read only. Reading over the XML manually is what I tried to do as I have an example PPTX generated by a human that I can compare to. The problem is its tedious, but if that's the only way I suppose I should get to it.

Comment: @thatidiotguy found any solution for the same? I am struggling with that too.

Comment: @Sak I have found no solution other than manually going over XML and comparing it to an example PPTX file put together by a human. Sometimes I cannot figure out the issues and I have to just restart and try again. Sorry I can not be of more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is natural that even official SDK from Microsoft can't cover all possible errors that Microsoft PowerPoint can produce.
What you can do in this case:

1. Try making minor changes to your document and save it again with Google Slides or with LibreOffice.
2. Try opening file in different versions of PowerPoint.
3. Debug problematic slides manually. Open XML in some text editor and check them.
4. Just recreate those slides in PowerPoint via copy-paste.

Most errors in PowerPoint relate to:

1. Mismatch between slide layout and master slide layout. <- this one is more common when writing to different templates.
2. Relationship Ids (rId) don't match.
3. Incorrect entries in [Content_Types].xml.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am already going over the XML manually. I was hoping for information about where PowerPoint may be logging errors. Do you know if PowerPoint does that?

Comment: @thatidiotguy you can try checking telemetry log which should contain error information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj230106.aspx - as far as I know, there is no more way for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file again in libreoffice and add a new slide. Then SAVE AS and create a new slideshow. Then try opening it in powerpoint and it should work. I have had similar issues be fixed this way.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for me as I am creating these with a script and they are instantly delivered to our clients.